# Ideas for inequality

Tags: inequality, integers

Given two non zero natuals $m$ and $n$, it is asked to prove that

$$ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m+1}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[m]{n+1}} \ge 1$$

I don't see how to start. the presence of $k^{\text{th}} $ roots makes it hard to manipulate.

any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1377289/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1999267/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467607/42969.

Comment: Yet another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2494605/42969.

Comment: [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that by [**Bernoulli inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) in the form $(1+x)^r\le 1+rx$ for $0\le r\le1$

- $\sqrt[n]{m+1}\le 1+\frac m n$
- $\sqrt[m]{n+1}\le 1+\frac n m$

therefore

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m+1}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[m]{n+1}} \ge \dfrac{1}{1+\frac m n}+\dfrac{1}{1+\frac n m}= \frac n{n+m}+\frac m{m+n}= 1$$

Comment: This has been asked and answered multiple times. You already answered an identical question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2972343/42969.

Comment: @MartinR I had the feeling to have already used that. But I cannot remember exactly when or if it was a similar or an identical question.

Comment: Have you heard about [Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969)? [This query](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Bm%2B1%7D%7D%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%5Bm%5D%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%20%5Cge%201%24&p=1) finds multiple identical questions within seconds. – And don't forget to cast a “close as duplicate” vote on this one!